# QML: access parent from non-visual item in C++

Tags: c++, qml, qtquick2

In my app I have a custom item derived from QObject. In specified moment I need to access its parent. But since this item is not QQuickItem descendant there is no `parentItem()` here.

QML:

```
Item {
    id: root
    MyItem {
        id: myitem
    }
}
```

C++

```
class MyItem : public QObject {
public:
    explicit MyItem(QObject *parent = 0) {
        // parent is always NULL here
    }
}
```

So my question - how can I access parent of non-visual QML item in C++?

Comment: `QObject` has the `parent()` method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to access the parent item from the `MyItem` constructor. QML first constructs the object, then sets its `parent` property to the appropriate item from QML hierarchy.

However, after the object is constructed, calling the `QObject::parent` method will give the results you expect. By the time when `Component.onCompleted` is called, the parent will be set. You can finish your object initialization with parent data from that handler.

Comment: Yes, sure `parent()` is what I need. Mistakenly I was expected to get it in constructor.